# Is there a "Sum" function?

Tags: powershell, sum

I've got following code snippet:

```powershell
> 1..10|%{$count=0}{$count+=$_}{$count}
55
> 1..10|Sum
```

The last line obviously shows an error since there is no "Sum" function. Is there a convenient way to sum items in PowerShell?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`Measure-Object` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx):

```powershell
PS > 1..10 | Measure-Object -Sum
Count    : 10
Average  : 
Sum      : 55
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :     
PS > (1..10 | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
55
PS >
```

Note that it also works with properties of objects:

```powershell
PS > ('abc', 'def', 'ghi') | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length
Count    : 3
Average  : 
Sum      : 9
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : Length
PS >
```

In the above example, we sum the lengths of the strings in the array by setting the `-Property` parameter to `Length`.